# Installing R package 'cubature': Error with compiler in remote server

Tags: r, compiler-errors, remote-server, slurm

I'm trying to install an R package 'cubature' in a Linux-based remote server which uses SLURM as manager.

Given that I'm a user of the server, I do not have root access. I tried to install the R package locally, but I do get the following error:

```
In file included from ./src/divonne/common.c:14:0,
                 from ./src/common/CSample.c:77,
                 from ./src/divonne/Divonne.c:14:
./src/divonne/Split.c: In function ‘SolveEqs’:
./src/divonne/Split.c:119:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
   for(int first_time = 1 ; c >= cut; --c) {
   ^
./src/divonne/Split.c:119:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make[1]: *** [libcuba.a(Divonne.o)] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/RtmpKH27PL/R.INSTALLa8387b918120/cubature/src/Cuba-4.2'
make: *** [cuba.ts] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cubature’
```

It seems that R cannot find the right compiler for installing the R package.
Do you have any suggestion on what I should do?

Comment: I think neither SLURM nor "remote" are perfectly relevant to this. It would appear that the system on which you want to install it has an older version of `gcc` available than `cubature` is configured for. As the remote admins if they have multiple `cc` versions available, including something more modern.

Comment: You can try `module avail gcc` to look for more recent versions of GCC. Many clusters use env modules to manage multiple software versions